# Probability that the player wins a pass line bet with a 4 on the first roll

Tags: probability, solution-verification, gambling

**Precalculus textbook problem (self-study)**: In the game of craps, there are two ways a player can win a pass line bet. The player wins immediately if two dice are rolled and their sum is 7 or 11 . If their sum is $4,5,6,8,9$, or 10 , the player can still win a pass line bet if this same number (called the point) is rolled again before a 7 is rolled. Find the probability that the player wins a pass line bet with a 4 on the first roll.

**Textbook answer in back of book**: 1/36

**Question**: How did they get this answer? Is my solution below right?

**My solution**: There are infinitely many ways to win after first rolling a sum of 4. The second roll could be a 4, for example.  Or the second roll might not be 4 but it might be different than 7.  And so on. So you could win on the second roll, the third roll, the fourth roll, and on and on.

The probability of rolling a sum of 4 is 3/36.

The probability of rolling a sum different than 4 and 7 is 27/36.

Winning on the second roll or on the third roll are independent events, and so on.

So the probability of rolling a sum of 4 first and then winning the pass line bet is

$$
\frac{3}{36}\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left[\left(\frac{27}{36}\right)^i\frac{3}{36}\right]= \frac{3}{36}\cdot\frac{3}{36}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{27}{36}} = \frac{1}{36}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct.  Here's another approach.  Let $p$ be the probability that, after the first roll of $4$, the second $4$ appears before the first $7$.  Then by conditioning on whether the next roll is $4$, $7$, or something else, we find that
\begin{align}
p &= \mathbb{P}[\text{$4$ before $7$}] \\
&= \mathbb{P}[4]\cdot \mathbb{P}[\text{$4$ before $7$}\mid4] + \mathbb{P}[7]\cdot \mathbb{P}[\text{$4$ before $7$}\mid7] + \mathbb{P}[\text{other}]\cdot \mathbb{P}[\text{$4$ before $7$}\mid \text{other}] \\
&= \frac{3}{36}\cdot 1 + \frac{6}{36}\cdot 0 + \frac{27}{36}\cdot p
\end{align}
yielding $p=\frac{3/36}{9/36}=\frac{1}{3}$.  Hence the desired probability is
$$\mathbb{P}[4]\cdot p=\frac{3}{36}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{36}.$$

Comment: Conditioning is outside the scope of the text.  Can you provide more detail/explanation of what it means (definition) so I can see how that gives the equation you have for $p$?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

Comment: $p$ is the probability of the event that the second 4 appears before the first 7.  How to write this event down as a set?  It's the set of all number of rolls where the 4 appears before the 7?  If so, then I think I can see how to partition the event as you say, and then apply the Law of Total Probability you linked to.

Comment: Yes, you can think of the event as a set of finite strings of rolls, each with no 7, and no 4 until the end.

Comment: Ah, got it.  All such strings of length 1, strings of length 2, strings of length 3, and so on.  Is it then though a "conditional probability" like in the link or is the Law of Total Probability the same or something?

Comment: I added some detail to make the application of the law of total probability more explicit.